# Is it possible to define on $V = Z_{4}$ the structure of a vector space over $GF(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Is it possible to define on $V = Z_{4}$ the structure of a vector space over $GF(2)$ in such a way that the vector addition is the usual addition in $Z_{4}$?

Comment: No in a $\Bbb{F}_2$ vector space $x+x=2x=0$

Comment: The only finite abelian groups on which you can define a vector space structure are elementary abelian $p$-groups, because the additive group of a finite vector space must be an elementary abelian $p$-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is NOT.

$$ a+a = 0 $$

in linear spaces over GF(2) but not necessarily in $\mathbb Z_4,\ $
e.g. $1+1\ne 0$ in $\mathbb Z_4$.

This means that there is no isomorphism between the additive group of any linear space over GF(2) and the abelian group $\ \mathbb Z_4.$

Comment: so which condition in the definition of a vector space will be broken? My guess is the distribution of scalar multiplication over field addition ...... correct?

Comment: There is no "definition" yet of $\ \mathbb Z_4\ $ as a linear space over GF(2), hence there is nothing to break. I've added an additional explanation anyway. I can, of course, explain why a+a=0 in any linear space over GF(2) (should I?). This would enforce the already given argument, since $\ 1+1\ne 0\ $ in $\ \mathbb Z_4.$

Comment: One can also show that group $\ \mathbb Z_4\ $ cannot be enhanced to serve a field any linear space over any field. This would go beyond the OP's question though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, and can be generalized. Let $K/GF(p^n)$ ($p$ is prime) be a vector space and let $a = a_1k_1 + \cdots + a_nk_n$ be an element in said vector space. Here, the $a_i$'s are elements in $GF(p^n)$ and the $k_i$'s are in $K$. See that adding $a$ to itself $p$ times will yield zero. (The characteristic of $GF(p^n)$ is $p$.) In fact, $ma = 0$ if and only if $m$ is a multiple of $p$.