# Understanding question 56 in Golan's Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question says:

Is it possible to define on $V = Z_{4}$ the structure of a vector space over $GF(2)$ in such a way that the vector addition is the usual addition in $Z_{4}$?

**My question is:**

I know by the definition of the vector space that the vector space must be defined on a field, so is the question saying that we have this vector space $\mathbb{Z_{4}(\mathbb{Z_{2}})}$ i.e. the field is $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$? if yes then what should be the relation between the vector addition and the field addition? if not, then what is the meaning of the question?

**Note:**

This question has an answer here [Is it possible to define on $V = Z_{4}$ the structure of a vector space over $GF(2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340624/is-it-possible-to-define-on-v-z-4-the-structure-of-a-vector-space-over-gf), but my problem is that I am not understanding the question first and hence I am not understanding the answer.

Comment: well, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is an abelian group, so you should define a scalar multiplication such that the additive group underlying it is $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But also one more question, do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$ or really $\mathbb{Z}_4$, as I know the second one as localisation along $4$, which I think is a little bit advanced for linear algebra.

Comment: Yes I mean $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$@Enkidu

Comment: actually I do not know the difference @Enkidu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to know that you can break up a vector space into two components - the set of vectors and the 'scalars' or field elements that act on the vectors.

You already know how the vectors will behave on their own, i.e. you are given that the set of vectors is just $\mathbb Z_4$ and the addition on it needs to be the standard addition.

You also already know how the field works, as you are given that the field is $GF(2)$.

All that is left in combining the set of vectors, i.e. $\mathbb Z_4$ and the set of scalars, i.e. $GF(2)$, is defining how the two, scalars and vectors, will interact. Specifically, how does multiplication between each scalar and vector work.

Multiplication between a field $\left(F\right)$ element and a vector in any vector space $\left(V\right)$ needs to satisfy the following properties:

**Rule 1:** $a(b \mathbf{v} )=(ab)\mathbf{v}\quad \forall a,b\in F,\; \forall v\in V$

**Rule 2:** $1\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}\quad \forall v\in V$

**Rule 3:** $a(\mathbf{u+v})=a\mathbf{u}+a\mathbf{v}\quad \forall a\in F,\; \forall u,v\in V$

**Rule 4:** $(a+b)\mathbf{v}=a\mathbf{v}+b\mathbf{v}\quad \forall a,b\in F, \; \forall v\in V$

The question is asking whether given the fact a set of vectors, $\mathbb Z_4$ (that obey standard rules of addition), and a field, $GF(2)$, is there a way to define multiplication between members of the field and the vectors such that the multiplication obeys all of the above **Rules: 1-4** to make a true vector space with vectors in $\mathbb Z_4$ and scalars in $GF(2)$.

Comment: so which condition in the definition of a vector space will be broken? My guess is the distribution of scalar multiplication over field addition ...... correct?

Comment: Rule4 I mean ..... correct?

Comment: @hopefully Yes - this is demonstrated in the answer you have linked in your question